# Ansible & rbash

Tags: bash, ansible

I want to manage a bunch of devices running `/bin/rbash` as the default shell with Ansible.

The problem is that Ansible always tries to execute a list of commands that `rbash` doesn't like at all:

```
umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ./ansible-tmp-1460362654.19-62671997084808 `\" && echo \"` echo ./ansible-tmp-1460362654.19-62671997084808 `\"
```

Any ideas how can I avoid this commands?

To clarify: I want to change the shell Ansible uses, and there is only one user available.

Comment: Don't use rbash or any other restricted shell, or you're going to have a bad time. Log in to another account which doesn't use a restricted shell.

Comment: The problem is that the devices already have rbash, because someone found that useful. Now, I want to change that with Ansible.

Comment: Try logging in as root, that is going to be your last resort.

Comment: The root user is not available. If I login I can change the shell but Ansible execute those commands and rbash doesn't like them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm. I think you can get around this with [ansible's raw module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html).

Remember that while rbash is a restricted shell, it's entirely possible to start an unrestricted subshell; it's meant more to prevent accidents than to provide security.

So this is what I would do. I've tested this and confirmed it successfully changes a restricted shell. Note that it has to prompt for a password, because `chsh` prompts for a password and this isn't avoidable without root access.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: username
  tasks:
    - name: change shell
      raw: "bash -c 'chsh -s /bin/bash' <<< '{{chsh_password}}' "
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "chsh_password"
      prompt: "Password"
```

Comment: The problem is that rbash does not like use `/bin/rbash` for running commands so for example, you cannot run `/bin/rbash -c echo hi`. I modify executable in ansible.cfg to run rbash instead of /bin/sh so now Ansible run `rbash -c echo hi` and not `/bin/sh -c echo hi` or `/bin/rbash -c echo hi`. And now, with your playbook everything works! :D thanks!!!